# VS code how to support es6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.js";
import App from "./App.vue";

let vm = new Vue({
    el: "#box",
    // template:"<div>hello</div>"

    render: h => h(App)
});
```

In the vs code to write es6 code, there will always be an error

[image]

Comment: Does https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript work for you?

Comment: check this one http://donovanbrown.com/post/Enabling-jshint-es6-support-in-VS-Code

Comment: Finally solved the problem, very grateful

Comment: Next time, please post code as a snippet instead of an image. Also, include what errors you are getting so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Thank you, next time I will pay attention to the problem you said, the first use of this site, will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a bit of configuration for VS code to properly highlight your ES6 syntax.

1. Create a file called `jsconfig.json` in the root of your project.
2. Write this into the file:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "ES6",
           "module": "commonjs"
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps anyone with a syntax highlighting issue!

Sources:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_writing-jsconfigjson
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/07/06/visual-studio-code-es6/